# Show that if $f : [1, 2] →\Bbb R$ is a continuous then there exists $\gamma\in (1, 2)$ with $f(\gamma) = \frac{1}{1 − \gamma}+ \frac{1}{2 − \gamma}.$

Tags: real-analysis

Show that if $f : [1, 2] →\Bbb R$ is a continuous function then there exists $\gamma\in (1, 2)$ such that $$f(\gamma) = \frac{1}{1 − \gamma}+ \frac{1}{2 − \gamma}.$$

I have been trying to understand what the question wants me to do but I can't figure it out. Please help!

Comment: Consider the function $g(x)=f(x)-\frac1{1-x} - \frac1{2-x}$ in $(1,2)$ and see what happens when $x\to 1^+$ and when $x\to 2^-$

Answer (score 3):

Consider the function $$g:x\mapsto  f(x)-\frac{1}{1 − x}- \frac{1}{2 − x},1<x<2.$$ Since $\lim_{x\to 1+}f(x)=f(1)$ and $\lim_{x\to 2-}f(x)=f(2)$ we have, $$\lim_{x\to 1+}g(x)=+\infty,$$$$\lim_{x\to 2-}g(x)=-\infty.$$ So by **intermediate value theorem** we have $\gamma\in (1,2)$ such that, $g(\gamma)=0$.

Comment: You should also note that $g$ is continuous

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I have not included this "Sum two continuous functions is contionuous".